# Attach to PyInstaller Python Interpreter

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Is it possible to find the filepath of the underlying "python.exe" that is bundled with my PyInstaller application? My end goal: I would essentially like to run a separate python file, say in VS Code using the same interpreter that is bundled with my installed PyInstaller application. I am creating a "one-folder" application.

I am aware of the following documentation, but not sure how to apply it to my end goal.
https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/advanced-topics.html?highlight=meipass

Comment: Did you try seeing what the value of `sys.executable` is?

Comment: It points to the entry point executable of the project, i.e. `ProjectA.exe`. Although this isn't the python.exe, unless it is embedded within it somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately sys.executable will not work for the following reason from the docs… https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0 “When a normal Python script runs, sys.executable is the path to the program that was executed, namely, the Python interpreter. In a frozen app, sys.executable is also the path to the program that was executed, but that is not Python; it is the bootloader in either the one-file app or the executable in the one-folder app. This gives you a reliable way to locate the frozen executable the user actually launched.”